# Getting python error when redeploying elastic beanstalk with same code in .ebextension

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I don't know why I'm getting error when redeploying ebs with same build. When creating a new ebs env everything is good but when redeploying ebs env geting python error.

````
    **CONFIG FILE**
    
    ```files:
      "/root/default.json":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
          {
              "agent": {
                      "run_as_user": "root",
                      "metrics_collection_interval": 60
              },
              "metrics": {
                      "metrics_collected": {
                              "mem": {
                                      "measurement": [
                                              "mem_used_percent"
                                      ],
                                      "metrics_collection_interval": 60
                              },
                              "disk": {
                                      "measurement": [
                                              "used_percent"
                                      ],
                                      "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
                                      "resources": [
                                              "/"
                                      ]
                              }
                      },
                      "append_dimensions": {
                              "InstanceId": "${aws:InstanceId}"
                      }
               }
          }
    container_commands:
      00_wget_pkg:
        cwd: /root
        command: wget https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/amazon_linux/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm
      01_install:
        cwd: /root
        command: sudo rpm -U /root/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm
      02_change_own:
        cwd: /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent
        command: chown -R root:root var && chown -R root:root logs &&  chown -R root:root etc
      03_change_dr:
        cwd: /root
        command: mv default.json /etc/amazon/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d/
      04_start_cw:
        cwd: /root
        command: systemctl stop amazon-cloudwatch-agent && systemctl start amazon-cloudwatch-agent && systemctl enable amazon-cloudwatch-agent
      05_start_cw:
        cwd: /root
        command: rm -rf /root/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm*```
    
    **ERROR**
    
    2021-09-28 11:33:45,384 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
    2021-09-28 11:33:45,387 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPostBuild
    2021-09-28 11:33:45,389 [INFO] Running config postbuild_0_T8
    2021-09-28 11:33:45,977 [INFO] Command 00_wget_pkg succeeded
    2021-09-28 11:33:46,058 [ERROR] Command 01_install (sudo rpm -U /root/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm) failed
    2021-09-28 11:33:46,058 [ERROR] Error encountered during build of postbuild_0_T8: Command 01_install failed
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 573, in run_config
        CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 273, in build
        self._config.commands)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
        raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
    cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_install failed
    2021-09-28 11:33:46,059 [ERROR] -----------------------BUILD FAILED!------------------------
    2021-09-28 11:33:46,059 [ERROR] Unhandled exception during build: Command 01_install failed
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 176, in <module>
        worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 135, in build
        Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 561, in build
        self.run_config(config, worklog)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 573, in run_config
        CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 273, in build
        self._config.commands)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
        raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
    cfnbootstrap.construction_errors.ToolError: Command 01_install failed
````

I don't know why I'm getting error when redeploying ebs with same build. When creating a new ebs env everything is good but when redeploying ebs env geting python error.

Comment: What is an exact version of your EB platform that you are using?

Comment: I don't know I'm using elastic beanstalk aws service

Comment: To see more detailed logs about why its failing, download 'Full logs' from EB and check this file -> var/log/cfn-init-cmd.log

Comment: [INFO] Command 01_install
[INFO] -----------------------Command Output-----------------------
[INFO]  Retrieving https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/amazon_linux/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.rpm
[INFO]  Preparing...                          ########################################
[INFO]   package amazon-cloudwatch-agent-1.247349.0b251399-1.x86_64 is already installed
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Exited with error code 1

Comment: I know it's already installed but how to stop this command to not to execute if cloudwatch already installed

Comment: @DeepakKumar1 You have to remove the commands from 'container_commands' from config file. You can read more about this here - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-container-commands

Comment: @GowthamBhat so I've to use commands instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [commands](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-ec2.html#linux-commands) in this case as these commands should run before your application server is started. But that alone will not solve the problem.

Container commands and Commands run **every time** you deploy / re-deploy a version of the EB environment.

For each of these commands you can have a **test directive** which will decide if the command should be run. Syntax -

```
commands:
  command: command to run
  test: conditions for command
```

The command will run only if the test command returns True or 0

In your case, the commands are installing and setting up amazon-cloudwatch-agent for your environment. They are throwing error during re-deploy as the amazon-cloudwatch-agent is **already installed**. To avoid this have a test command to check if the package is already installed.

Going through [AWS Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/download-cloudwatch-agent-commandline.html), there is another easier way to install the package using yum package manager.

Try running only the below commands,

```
commands:
  00_install_cw_agent:
    command: yum install amazon-cloudwatch-agent
    test: ! yum list installed amazon-cloudwatch-agent
  01_start_cw:
    command: systemctl stop amazon-cloudwatch-agent && systemctl start amazon-cloudwatch-agent && systemctl enable amazon-cloudwatch-agent
```

The first command will install amazon-cloudwatch-agent package. But it will only run if the test command returns 0.

The test command [returns 0](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122682/418334) if the package is already installed, opposite of what we want, so we negate it using **!** operator. So the command runs only if the package is not already installed.

We are not using any test directive for second command as it needs to run every time you deploy a new version.

Let me know if this works for you.

**Edit** -
For some reason any file created / copied into amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d directory before [configure stage](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/platforms-linux-extend.html#platforms-linux-extend.workflow) is being deleted by EB

So try using the `container_commands` to move the file and restart the cloudwatch agent.

If this doesn't work, you can create a **predeploy** platform hook for this job.

Comment: Thanks now it's running good but still facing a little problem that idk why amazon-cloudwatch is not starting although I added the command to start amazon-cloudwatch but still not starting

Comment: Check 'cfn-init-cmd' log for what output you are getting for 01_start_cw - command. If that doesn't help and this is a blocker issue, you can enable cw agent from EB configuration GUI. If you are enabling it in GUI, remove the command

Comment: It's try to start cloudwatch before moving default.json that's why but idk, I wrote command 
  to move json file to amazon-cloudwatch-agent.d directory before starting cloudwatch then why it's running that command first